# Image of a set under a non-constant holomorphic map

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, riemann-surfaces

Suppose $p_1, \cdots p_n$ are points on the compact Riemann surface $X$ and $X^{\prime}=X\setminus \{p_1,\cdots, p_n\}$. Suppose \begin{equation*}
    f:X^{\prime} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}
\end{equation*}
is a non-constant holomorphic function. Show that the image of $f$ becomes arbitrarily close to every $c \in \mathbb{C}$.

Here is my argument.
According to the question we are asked to show that $\overline{f(X^{\prime})}=\mathbb{C}$, i.e., the image of $X^{\prime}$ under $f$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}.$
For a contradiction assume that $f(X^{\prime})$ is not dense in $\mathbb{C}$. Then this means that there exists an open subset(a ball of radius $r$ centered at $c$) in $\mathbb{C}$, say $B_{r}(c)$ so that $B_{r}(c) \cap f(X^{\prime})=\emptyset $. This is to say that $f(z)\neq c$ for some $z \in X^{\prime}$.  If this is the case then one can define a function $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)-c}$ which is holomorphic on $X^{\prime}$. Since $|f(z)-c|>r$, one has $|g(z)|< \frac{1}{r}$. Thus the function $g$ is holomorphic and bounded. But I could not complete the proof. I could not even use the condition that the points $p_i$ are removed.  How do I need to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to evaluate your proof on the whole, but if you have  indeed found $g: X \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ holomorphic then by compactness (and, I assume, connectedness) of $X$ we must have $g$ constant. That would force $f$ to be constant.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop Yes I have found a function $g$ on $X^{\prime}$ but the thing is that how do I extend this function to the Riemann surface $X$. If $g$ can be extended then it would give us a non-constant holomorphic function on a compact Riemann surface which is impossible. But still, we didn't even use the removed points $p_i$ and that's what bothers me.

Comment: Oh my apologies, I misread this and thought $g$ was defined on all of $X$. I'm afraid I don't know how to answer this question then.